# How to cover piece of code using test class which is checking if its sandbox or Production

Tags: apex, code-coverage, sandbox, test-setup

I have below Peice of code which is chekcing if its sandbox then run If part else run Else part

```
    if(runningInASandbox()) {
                    return getSsoRedirect('one', startUrl, requestAttributes); //call sso flow 
                }
                else {
                    return getSsoRedirect('two',startUrl, requestAttributes); //call sso flow 
                }
```

Now I am running test class its covering if part ,beacasue i am running from sandbox.how to cover else part as well in test class.Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Since the result will not change typically from run to run you need a way to be able to set the result if you want. Lazy loading helps. Then in your test you can set it to return a value

```
@testVisible private static Organization org {
      Get{
              If(org == null){
                     Org = [select isSandbox from organization limit 1];

               }

               Return org;

       }

       Set;

}


Public static Boolean runningInASandbox(){

     Return org.isSandbox;

}
```

Then in your tests set

```
ClassName.org = new Organization(isSandbox = true;
```

Note I typed this on mobile so will probably be buggy or need slight mods